# HTML | Centering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble centering my image when i use particles.js. The image is centering however it is slightly off-center. Why is it doing this and how can i center it?

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>particles.js demo</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="particles-js" width='100%'></div>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/index.js">
</script>
<img id='downarrow' height="75" width="75" src='images/arrowdown.png'>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
body {
margin: 0;
height: 2000px;
width: 100%;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
#particles-js {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #00a4ff;
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/yHL4C4u.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

#downarrow {
margin-left: 50%;
}
img {
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `left: 50%;` - that will put the left edge of the image at 50% width of the page. If you want the image to be centered, add `transform: translateX(-50%);`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00a4ff;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/yHL4C4u.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#downarrow {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js" width='100%'></div>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/index.js">
</script>
<img id='downarrow' height="75" width="75" src='images/arrowdown.png'>
```

Comment: What would i do if i want the image to be placed at the bottom of the sky image?

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative `margin-left` to pull the image back to the center:

```
#downarrow {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -37px; /* Half of the image width */
}
```